# Overloaded operator delete in dylib replaces system operator in OSX

Tags: c++, cocoa, macos, operator-overloading

I have a dylib written in C++ which has an overloaded `operator new` and `delete`.

When a link my cocoa application with my dylib I have a `BAD_ACCESS_ERROR` because Cocoa tries to free memory with my `operator delete` from my dylib.

So I think that I can use the unexported_symbols_list options, but what is the decorated names for `operator delete, delete[], new, new[], new(..)`?

Comment: Can’t you put the definitions in an unnamed namespace to prevent name clashes when exporting?

Comment: @Konrad, you cannot have `operator new` implemented inside `namespace`. http://www.ideone.com/FIkn1. I have also asked an question sometime back regarding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `nm` tool to extract the exported symbols from your lib and `c++filt` to demangle then and find which ones correspond to the mentioned operators.